# OpenCV VideoWriter filps video

Tags: java, opencv, kotlin, video, java-native-interface

I'm using OpenCV 4.5.2 with Java bindings, and trying to create a video from set of frames.

```
class OpenCVVideoWriter(
    size: com.domain.util.model.Size,
    frameRate: Float,
    outputFile: File
) {

    private var videoWriter = VideoWriter(
        outputFile.absolutePath,
        VideoWriter.fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'),
        frameRate.toDouble(),
        Size(size.width.toDouble(), size.height.toDouble()),
        true
    )

    private var currentFrame: Mat = Mat(size.height, size.width, CvType.CV_8UC3)

    init {
        if (!videoWriter.isOpened) {
            throw OpenCVException("Failed to open VideoWriter")
        }

        currentFrame = Mat(size.height, size.width, CvType.CV_8UC3)
    }

    fun writeFrame(data: ByteArray) {
        currentFrame.put(0, 0, data)
        videoWriter.write(currentFrame)
    }

    fun release() {
        videoWriter.release()
        currentFrame.release()
    }

    private companion object {
        init {
            System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME)
        }
    }
}
```

Frames are OK and I've also dumped the `ByteArray`s passed to VideoWriter as `*.bmp`, all of them are fine.

[image: Original frame]

But the final video is flipped (not rotated but flipped vertically):

[image: Flipped video]

I've used the same code (but with a bit older version of OpenCV) before in an older project, and it worked correct there (but I can't try it again with that project as I don't have an access to it).

UPD. If I write the frame with OpenCV `Imgcodecs.imwrite("/tmp/frame0.jpg", currentFrame)`, it's flipped too.

How to fix it?

Comment: play the video with VLC. in your screenshots, what are you using to view that data?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz it's macOS QuickTime Player. Just tested with VLC, it's flipped too.

Comment: use `imshow` and `waitKey` to view the data while your program runs (or some other means to display it before encoding to a file).